# Using Flat List with objectMap

Tags: reactjs, react-native, foreach, react-native-flatlist

Im using [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#normalizedata-schema) to normalize the api response based on id. So the final normalized response will be

```
{
  "names": {
    "12": {
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Status": "0",
      "Count": 11,
    },
    "31": {
      "Name": "CDE",
      "Status": "1",
      "Count": 12,
    }
  }
}
```

How i can use this names object map in a flat list. Its not an array  but an object map.
What's the best way to do this?

PS: I know there is lodash [_.values()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#values) function, but i think it will slow for a huge response.

Answer (score 2):

First you can change your object to return an array with `Object.keys`

This your data

```
{
  "names": {
    "12": {
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Status": "0",
      "Count": 11,
    },
    "31": {
      "Name": "CDE",
      "Status": "1",
      "Count": 12,
    }
  }
}
```

you can do with

```
const dataname = data.names
const datanamearr = Object.keys(dataname).map(key => dataname[key])
```

this will return an array

then you can render your data to `FlatList` with a map function

```
{datanamearr.map((item) =>
    <FlatList
      data={item}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.Name}</Text>}
    />
  )
}
```